Debouncing schematic vs the placement
I have the schematic for my debouncing figured out but want to see if the placement of my components is correct.



The placement does not matter much.
The largest stress on the system will be pushing the button, which causes the capacitor to discharge with an initial 33mA cuŕrent.

Thanks @Justme.

@Newbi_EE Suggestion for future, if there is no other reason for a comment than just saying "thank you", it is customary here to not send it. The upvotes and if it is worthy of it, the accept as answer buttons are sufficient.

If the switch input will be used by firmware on the MCU, then debouncing in hardware is not necessary at all - it's more robust to have it debounced in firmware, and more flexible too.
So it would help if you explained why you think you need the debouncing. Otherwise it's a fair assumption that you may not need it. So the problem may simplify to "placement irrelevant since components not needed" :)
You should definitely be asking about placement of decoupling capacitors around the MCU and other fast chips, and the layout of any voltage regulators - especially the switching ones, but LDOs also need some care. Feel free to edit the question to add those.
